# Good resolution for a sticker?

Tags: print-design

I'm quite a newbie to designing.

Do you think this image has a good enough resolution for printing a 50 x 50 mm sticker?

[image]

*[Link to file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/40cu3acb81w7jbi/sticker.jpg?dl=0)*

Comment: Keep in mind that the thin font might be difficult to read at small sizes, and that many stickers are meant to be read from a distance (think bumper stickers / laptop stickers). Others, like labels, might be fine smaller.

Comment: Also be aware that light grey grid will be difficult to maintain or may be lost. Anything less than a 5% screen of an ink can be "iffy" on press. It takes a quality print house to maintain screens under 5%. And an *exceptional* print house to maintain a 1% or 2% screen.

Comment: As an ex-pre-press operator, I'd have to ask why you don't just send the file through as a vector in a .pdf / .eps file?

Comment: @Aaron.. yes I'll be sending as a pdf. But used jpg here for easy reference. Thanks for all the tips guys.

Comment: Resolution is not your issue here if you are sending vectors. You will likely run into issues because of the halftone (lpi) caused by the thin and light elements. IMO your image probably isn't suitable for printing, but for reasons other than the resoluion.

Answer (score 6):

Of course yes.

Your image is 50 x 50 cm! at 72 PPI

[image: 50 x 50 cm]

Converted to 300 PPI which is an optimal resolution, the final size is 12 x 12 cm

[image: 12 x 12 cm]

At 50 x 50 mm, the final resolution is more than 730 PPI

[image: 50 x 50 mm]